# How to keep track of questions or answers I upvoted/downvoted?

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, bookmarks, votes

There doesn't seem to be a favorite button for answers, so the natural remedy seems to be allowing tracing of vote history. Is this something already possible that I am missing?

Comment: You can see your voting history at http://mathoverflow.net/users/4923/john-jiang?tab=votes. -- Though you won't be notified when
answers which you upvoted get changed.

Comment: I am puzzled why you tagged again "community-wiki". The tag community-wiki is for questions about the meta-subject community-wiki posts, which seems not at all applicable. If you want a question to be community-wiki you should flag for a moderator (but it'd be unusual on meta).

Comment: @quid: I don't understand what community wiki is apparently. To me it was synonymous to meta.

Comment: I see. This explains it in detail http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts (not everything applies here though). In brief, a community wiki post is a post with the status of being more collaborative than a usual post. Basically you can ignore it though; it is not very important.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Also I realize the UI was pretty obvious already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by Stefan Kohl it is possible to trace ones votes in the [votes-tab](https://mathoverflow.net/users/current?tab=votes) on the [user-page](https://mathoverflow.net/users/current).

One can even filter by type of vote (up/down/open/close/delete/undelete), for example this are [all up-votes](https://mathoverflow.net/users/current?tab=votes&sort=upvote); filtering by type of post is not possible though.